# SAX Parser Error

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

Firstly here is a snippet the XML file that is troubling me. The full XML file is very large and contains lots of 'packages' all with different names.

```
<repo version="2">
    <package name="packageNameHere">
        <author>Some Author</author>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <description>A description</description>
        <dependencies/>
        <API>
            <max>0.1</max>
            <min>0.1</min>
        </API>
        <download>
            http://www.somedownload.com/downloadfile.jar
        </download>
    </package>
</repo>
```

The program does an initial scan of the XML file and gets a list of all the names of the packages. Then the user is asked to input a package name. This `DefaultHandler` is used to locate information about that package.

```
private String packageToFind = null, currentElement = "";
public Package locatedPack = null;
private boolean finished = false;
private StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

public PackageSearchingRepoXMLHandler(String PackageToFind) {
    this.packageToFind = PackageToFind;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if(!finished && elementName.equals("package") && attributes.getValue("name").equals(packageToFind))
        locatedPack = new Package(packageToFind);
    else if(locatedPack != null && !finished) {
        currentElement = elementName;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String elementName) throws SAXException {
    if(locatedPack != null && !finished) {
        switch(currentElement) {
        case "author":
            locatedPack.setAuthor(buffer.toString());
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "version":
            locatedPack.setVersion(Double.parseDouble(buffer.toString()));
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "description":
            locatedPack.setDescription(buffer.toString());
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "dependencies":
            locatedPack.setDependencies(buffer.toString().split(", "));
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "max":
            locatedPack.setApiMAX(Double.parseDouble(buffer.toString()));
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "min":
            locatedPack.setApiMIN(Double.parseDouble(buffer.toString())); //This is line 157
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "download":
            try {
                locatedPack.setDownloadLink(new URL(buffer.toString()));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {/* Won't happen */}
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            break;
        case "package":
            finished = true;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    if (!finished)
        buffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}
```

A `NumberFormatException` is being thrown from the `Double.parseDouble()` part; the reason bit is `empty String`. I can't give you a specific line number because I am not given one by the console.

Anyone know the cause of this irritating error which causes my program not to output the data correctly? It's been bugging me for so long! :@

**EDIT**
Here is the exact stack trace (more of less, I removed all the swing nonsense...):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at [removed class/package info].endElement(PackageHelper.java:157)
```

Line 157 is highlighted in the code.

Comment: Surely Xpath would work better? `//package[@name=\""+packageToFind+"\"]` would find the element you want...

Comment: Maybe you have spaces somwhere in one of the xml elements where you expcet double value? Example: <max>_[space]0.1_[space]_</max>

Comment: The variable 'finished' is assigned to true when parsing the first </package> in the file. Subsequently, the `if` condition in the `characters` method never becomes true, and the buffer is never filled again.

Comment: @bmorris591 Yes it would... :/ Bit late now

Comment: I think @MartinEllis suggests you need to set it to `true` then you find the next `<package>` in your `startElement` method...

Comment: I updated this in the question. See the edit section.

Comment: No - you need to set `finished=false` on the line where you assign a new package.

Comment: Maybe new line is inserted somwhere? What exactly is your print stack trace saying?

Comment: But finished is already false... It is only ever set to true at the end of the package...

Comment: @Adam Added the stack trace

Comment: Maybe you have somwhere comma instead of dot? Exception cleary says that somwhere where you expect to have double value you have empty string. Try to run your code with smaller xml, for example only whit this one that you have inserted in this post.

Comment: @Kezz101: You can also try to catch NumberFormatException and then do something with this for example - print message to the user that the xml file is wrong. Code below results in the same exception that you get: `String doubleToParse = "";
  Double d = 0.0d;
  try {
   d = Double.parseDouble(doubleToParse);
  } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
  }
  System.out.println(d); `

Comment: @Adam I've run it with the small XML file file I posted and the exact same error comes up... I'll try catching the error tomorrow; I think I night of sleep will help solve this error...

Comment: @Kezz101 "But finished is already false... It is only ever set to true at the end of the package." Right, at the end of the first package in the file, you're setting it to true. Do you ever set it to `false` again? What value does it have when you parse the second `<package>` in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code and enter empty string in one of the max elements, the same error as you 
wrote appears. Anyway why do you use buffer? Try String maxString = new String(ch, start, length).

package XmlTest;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;

public class SAXTest {
    private static final String SPACE = " ";
    private static final String MAX = "Max";

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        boolean maxElement = false;

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(MAX)) {
                maxElement = true;
            }

        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            if (maxElement) {
                String maxString = new String(ch, start, length);
                Double maxDouble = Double.parseDouble(maxString);
                System.out.println(MAX + SPACE + maxDouble);
                maxElement = false;
            }
        }
    };

    saxParser.parse("your_xml_file.xml", handler);
}
```

}